# Laravel mock interface

Tags: laravel, phpunit

tell me how you can make fun of the interface. Otherwise, you replace the interface with the implemented class, then the test passes. The most interesting thing is that the code works with the interface.

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/Batisska/e64caf055f26f0441411c25da6f1f886)

With the interface, I get the error:

```
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException : Method send(<Any Arguments>) from Mockery_0_App_Services_SmsNotification_SmsInterface should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times
```

How do I implement the test?

Answer (score 0):

On line 36 of ExampleTest.php,

```
$user->notify(new CreateUploadUpdateTask(new SmsMessage()));
```

The notify() method comes from Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable trait, right? If so, you can fake the notification as described in [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mocking#notification-fake).

Besides, if you [send notifications using the Notification facade](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/notifications#using-the-notification-facade), then you can mock the facade as described in [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mocking#mocking-facades).

Please try to name your test classes and methods as descriptive as possible so that one can quickly realize what are you trying to test just from reading the test class or method name.